# Dog hairs Dog hairs Dog hairs.....everywhere hairs, but how to get rid of it

Tags: cleaning

I love my dog, but I totally hate the hairs what are almost everywhere. Even when you use a vacuum cleaner the hairs heap up in the brush. 
So what is a good way to minimize dog hairs in your house 
and what is the most easiest way to clean them?

Comment: FYI: Some breeds shed more than others. Look for the grooming necessities for your specific breed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the ultimate solution for this problem 2 years after I posted this question.

I've bought a "iLife V5s Pro Intelligente Robot"  (about € 185 / $ 150,-)
It cleans all the dog hairs automatic.
It's amazing. I remembered I posted this question and I want to share this solution with you
Hope it help you guys out.
(works only for hard floors like tiles, for carpets the result is poor)

Comment: I thought you were going to say that your solution was keeping your dog in an outside kennel or dog house ;-) thanks for coming back with what you actually used.

Answer (score 2):

A notable technique is to use a rubber glove. The dog hairs stick to the rubber glove because of static electricity, and you just have to literally "rinse" the glove and "repeat" the process when you accumulate an excess of dog hair.

Comment: You are free to add complete solutions here if you wish, but I had to remove the link-only parts of your answer and multiple comments. Links sending users elsewhere to find answers are are not considered answers in the context of this site. This site was built to create a collaborative work of sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information to work with here (dog breed, inside/outside, etc) but due to the fact that spring/summer is here I assume your dog is shedding. Shedding typically is a bodily response when warmer weather comes into play. Inside and short-haired dogs shed during this period as well.

The key is not to postpone the shedding -- accelerate it and get it over with. Make the pup stay outside for long periods of time in the heat. This will promote a higher/faster shed rate as the dog's system is trying to cope with the changing season.

Most important of course is to make sure the dog has PLENTY of available fresh water and food at all times, and make sure you brush them regularly (daily) and get the fluffs out.

I have a German Sheppard and she *just* finished shedding her coat. It was horrible and my wife hated her being in the house.

Comment: Could you add some details on how to clean up the hair that has already left the dog?

Comment: this, together with the answer of micsthepick is what you need

Answer (score 0):

First, get a special brush for your dog, and brush him/her every day before you let him/her in. 
For the hairs already in your house use rubber gloves (cheap method) or there are special things you can buy, but these are expensive.